# Why is there no difference in the two results between the global array and the local array?

Tags: c++, arrays, global, local

I turned global arrays into local arrays in the `main()` function to solve my homework for C++.  I expected the program to produce an error, but it outputs **the same result** without any error.

What's the reason for this problem?

Here's the first source code:

```cpp
#define DIM 9

int MaskA[DIM][DIM];
int LabelA[DIM][DIM];

inline int& mask(int x, int y) { return MaskA[y][x]; }
inline int& label(int x, int y) { return LabelA[y][x]; }

void main()
{
    int total=5;
    init(total);
}

void init(int total) {
    for (int y = 0; y < DIM; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
            mask(x, y) = 9;
            label(x, y) = 0;
        }
}
```

And, I changed it like this:

```cpp
#define DIM 9

inline int& mask(int x, int y) { return MaskA[y][x]; }
inline int& label(int x, int y) { return LabelA[y][x]; }

void main()
{
    int MaskA[DIM][DIM];
    int     LabelA[DIM][DIM];
    int total=5;
    init(total);
}

void init(int total) {
    for (int y = 0; y < DIM; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
            mask(x, y) = 9;
            label(x, y) = 0;
        }
}
```

I expected when the two arrays are local in the `main()` function, the `mask()` function and `label()` function don't work because the two arrays **are not in the `init()` function.**

I thought I got wrong concepts about global and local, so I searched for some helpful information and questions on this site, but none of them could help me to solve this problem.

Can you explain why this program works well without any problem?

Comment: Your `init()` function doesn't have a direct reference to these arrays, why would you expect an error there?? Also you still left the global definition, when putting those arrays into main. I haven't the slightest idea, which error you expect to see from your change.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/deA4lo), the 2nd code fails to compile, as expected

Comment: Several edits from OP later ... :-P

Answer (score 1):

In the original version of your question, you left in the global arrays, but added local arrays to `main()`. The local arrays *shadow* the global arrays only when used inside of `main()` itself, while `mask()` and `label()` still use the global arrays. In that version of your question, both codes have the same result because only the global arrays are being used for anything, the local arrays are not being used at all.

Then you edited your question to remove the global arrays, and now [that code fails to compile](https://ideone.com/deA4lo), as expected, since `mask()` and `label()` are trying to use arrays that have not been declared yet.

---

Note that in all version of your question, both codes fail to compile, because `main()` must return `int` not `void`, and `init()` is being called before it has been declared.